# Git Branch for Visual Studio project is incomplete

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with the GitHub extension.

I have been able to upload a pre-existing project from my Office PC to GitHub and then fetch it to my Home PC.  Both 'copies' can be edited, compiled, and run.

Now I am trying to create a Branch.  The local and remote repositories now exist but they are unusable- the 'references' folder was not replicated so the project will not compile.  Less serious (but more annoying) the Form Designer is unavailable in this copy of the project.

Did I miss something?

Comment: output window shows what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you create a new project, Visual Studio will add a .gitIgnore file to prevent you from accidentally committing unwanted binary files.

*.dll is generally on that list. If you need them in your repo, you can force-add them (`get add *.dll -f`. Or exclude the references folder from the gitIgnore by adding `!references/` to it.

The designer should work after that, it depends on the binaries to load.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Once I have added the `!refernces/` line to the .gitignore how do I force VS to re-fetch the files.  Also why did the Master branch not exclude the references folder but the branch did?

Comment: You can't re-fetch the files until they are actually committed. So you'll need to perform this action on the machine that actually has the files, commit them there and push them to GitHub before you can fetch them.